# Downloading html source on Android Crashes the Application

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to download some website's code to my app like this:

```
 public void wypned(final View pwn) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://example.com");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent() ) );

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    result += line + "\n";
    }
}
```

And all i got is fatal error. LogCat says:

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 on Android 3.x and up, you can't do network I/O on the main thread
```

Could someone tell me how to solve it? I've tried to do something with threads but it didn't work out.

Comment: try that in Async task's doInbackground method

Comment: You said you have already tried threads, can you be more specific about what you have tried and what was the problem you faced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an asyncTask for doing that :

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result>{

                        private Activity activity;
                        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
                            super();
                this.activity = activity;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Loading", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected Result doInBackground(Void... v) {
            //do your stuff here
            return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Finished.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


}
```

Call it from the activity:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(myActivity.this);
task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

All networking operations (as they are blocking) should be done on a separate thread. Android dev guide suggests this.

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

Create a separate thread for your networking operations, it's telling you that basically.

> Potentially long running operations such as network or database
>   operations, or computationally expensive calculations such as resizing
>   bitmaps should be done in a child thread

[Source1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) [Source2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html)